# What is pymunkoptions?

Tags: python, pymunk, arcade

I'm pretty frustrated and I'm not even sure where to start. I'm trying to install [python arcade](https://arcade.academy/) and it's going poorly.  I'm trying to run one of the tutorial scripts and I get back the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 4, in 
> import arcade
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/arcade/**init**.py", line 103, in 
> from .drawing_support import calculate_hit_box_points_detailed
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/arcade/drawing_support.py", line 7, in 
> import pymunkoptions
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymunkoptions'

pymunk is saying it's installed.  Does arcade not work on python 3.9?

Comment: This was fixed in a recent arcade version. The version contraint was added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I got round it by specifying that the version of pymunk needs to be 5.7.0 (apparently it's been updated since 5.7.0 and Arcade still needs to tweak some things to work properly).

In the requirements.txt in Pycharm (if you're following the instructions here: https://arcade.academy/venv_install/index.html), I put both:

arcade

pymunk==5.7.0

Did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks, this helped.

Answer (score 0):

File paths were setup incorrectly.